# Bootstrap remove left margin when filtering

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have got a view like this using bootstrap2.3.1:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3">text1</div>
    <div class="span3">text2</div>
    <div class="span3">text3</div>
    <div class="span3">text4</div>
</div>
```

When I filter this to only show the div with text2 I set the other divs display to none. But because the div with text1 is still first child the div with text2 has a left margin. How do I change this so it only puts margin-left: 0; to the first child with display block?

The view looks likes this when filtered:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3" style="display: none;">text1</div>
    <div class="span3">text2</div>
    <div class="span3" style="display: none;">text3</div>
    <div class="span3" style="display: none;">text4</div>
</div>
```

The margin got removed to the first child by the following CSS from bootstrap:

```
.row-fluid [class*="span"]:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

I think I should be doing something like this: (but than the right syntax)

```
.row-fluid [class*="span"]:first-child[display="block"] {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your bizzare selector ([demo](http://bootply.com/79127)):

```css
.row-fluid [class^="span"]:not([style="display: none;"]) {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Howerever, currently it's not possible to select first-of-class, so this rule will be applied to all matched elements. I suggest you to switch Bootstrap classes (`.spanX`) when showing/hiding elements.

Comment: Thanks for that. The right thing to do was: .row-fluid [class^="span"]:first-child([style="display: block;"]). Because It should only remove the margin-left of the first child with display = block. With yours all the margin-left were removed when all where display: block